# Heathrow visa waiver experience

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, lhr

I am travelling to the US via LHR on an Indian passport. I have a 10+ hour layover in LHR (land at 06:30 and take off at 17:00) with both flights from T5.

I was wondering if anyone has had experience with the UK transit without a visa program. I meet all the conditions but the website says that granting this waiver is at the discretion of the interviewing officer. So I'm looking for real-life experiences here. I haven't had the time to apply for a transit visa and I'm really hoping to get a chance to take some rest at a hotel near the airport and get a nice meal in.

This is my second trip to the US and I have also been to the UK twice before: once as a visitor and the second when my flight back from the US was delayed.

Comment: Don't worry. If everything is in order there is no need to fear that the discretion will be used against you. That discretion is always there for any type of visas but most of the people go through smoothly.

Comment: just an update. no hassles at the airport. the visa officer asked me if i was travelling alone and where i would get rest. I answered both questions and was given the visa.